# calculating ages in R by subtracting two dates columns

Tags: r, date

I have 2 columns with ~ 2000 rows of dates in them. One is a variable with a visit date (df$visitdate), and the other is a birth date of the individual (df$birthday).

Wondering if there is any simple way to subtract the visit date - birth date to create the variable "age at the time of the visit", accounting for leap years, etc.

I tried to use the following code (from an answer in a similar question) but it didn't work in my case.

find number of seconds in one year:

```
seconds_in_a_year <- as.integer((seconds(ymd("2010-01-01")) - seconds(ymd("2009-01-01"))))
```

now obtain number of seconds between the 2 dates you desire

```
seconds_between_dates <- as.integer(seconds(date1) - seconds(date2))
```

your final answer for number of years in floating points will be

```
years_between_dates <- seconds_between_dates / seconds_in_a_year
```

When I tried to apply this to my data frame (note: using variables rather than specific dates, so this may be the cause) I got the following:
  seconds_in_a_year <- as.integer((seconds(ymd(df$visitdate)) - seconds(ymd(df$birthday))))

Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion

Following the code along I got a final output of:

```
years_between_dates
```

[1] 1.157407e-05 [2] 1.157407e-05

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You said it didn't work "in your case"- well, what is your case? Could you show the data you are working with (e.g. what format the dates are in)? For example, posting the results of `dput(head(df))` would create a reproducible example that would help people answer

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting from a `Date` object another `Date` object gives you the time difference in days, e.g.

```
> dates = as.Date(c("2007-03-01", "2004-05-23"))
> 
> dates[1] - dates[2]
Time difference of 1012 days
```

So, assuming 365 days in a year

```
> age_time_visit = as.numeric(dates[1] - dates[2]) / 365
> age_time_visit
[1] 2.772603
```

Comment: But this approach won't account for leap days.  At the very least, try dividing by 365.2425.

Answer (score 0):

There are various answers for this scattered around the internet.

I think the one I've typically used was inspired by Professor Ripley:
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Calculate-difference-between-dates-in-years-td835196.html

```
age_years <- function(first, second) 
{ 
lt <- data.frame(first, second) 
age <- as.numeric(format(lt[,2],format="%Y")) - as.numeric(format(lt[,1],format="%Y")) 
first <- as.Date(paste(format(lt[,2],format="%Y"),"-",format(lt[,1],format="%m-%d"),sep="")) 
age[which(first > lt[,2])] <- age[which(first > lt[,2])] - 1 
age 
}
```

There's another approach at https://gist.github.com/mmparker/7254445

Or you you just want to raw, decimal value of years, you can get the number of days and divide by 365.2425

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that accounts for leap years (don't know if this has been done before, but suspect it has...).

```
get.age <- function(from, to) {
  require(lubridate)    # for leap_year(...)
  n   <- as.integer(to-from)
  n.l <- sum(leap_year(seq(from,to,by=1)))
  n.l/366 + (n+1-n.l)/365
}
get.age(as.Date("2009-01-01"),as.Date("2012-12-31"))  
# [1] 4 
get.age(as.Date("2012-01-01"),as.Date("2012-01-31"))   # 2012 was a leap year
# [1] 0.08469945
get.age(as.Date("2011-01-01"),as.Date("2011-01-31"))   # 2011 was not
# [1] 0.08493151
```

So the basic idea is to create a vector with one element for every day between `from` and `to` (inclusive), then for each day account for whether that day is part of a leap year or not. The we add up the leap year days and the non-leap year days separately and calculate the number of years as:

```
leap-year-days/366 + non-leap-year-days/365
```

This works for single dates (vectors of length 1). To enable this for columns of dates, as you asked, we use `Vectorize(...)`.

```
vget.age <- Vectorize(get.age)   # vectorized version
```

And then a demo:

```
# example data set
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
today <- as.Date("2015-09-09")
df <- data.frame(birth.date=today-sample(1000:10000,2000)) # 2000 birthdays
result <- vget.age(df$birth.date,today)                    # how old are they?
head(result)
# [1]  9.282192 11.909589 16.854795 25.115068  7.706849 24.865753
```